# RabbitMQ with TCP load-balanced consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, load-balancing, scaling

Need some tips on how I can get consumer load-balancing right with RabbitMQ.

The scenario is as below - 
I have 2 applications, let's say App1 & App2 (actually 2 stages of a single application), running on separate hosts (may or may not be in the same AZ) and rabbitMQ is used to hand-over half-done tasks from App1 to App2.

There are multiple instances of App1 and App2. Given the traffic volume, App1 is TCP load-balanced. I'd prefer App2 to be TCP load-balanced - so that new instances of App2 are brought up when required, etc. etc.

Now, with my understanding of RabbitMQ, a load-balancer can't obviously be used as a consumer. So I am thinking the setup could be as below -

Incoming Request -> LB -> App1 * N1 -> RabbitMQ -> workers -> LB -> App2 * N2

(The 'workers' will just hand-off the tasks to App2 instances via the LB)

PS - I will be using Celery. The AutoScale option is a possibility but I don't want to write my own dynamic scaling algo.

Comment: RabbitMQ can be configured in cluster and you can setup a load balancer in front of that cluster. The load balancer is not the consumer, the consumer is connected to a node in the cluster ass directed by the load balancer

Comment: You could use a TCP load balancer like HAProxy. But connection between RabbitMQ server and client are long running TCP connections. So a simple node shuffle on the client side may be enough and simple to manage (no need to have an HA TCP load balancer). At least, a RabbitMQ node that contains a replica queue will forward the message to the node that holds the master queue. The load balancing will not be really effective until it has this knowledge.

Comment: @Leon I am not worried much about load balancing the RabbitMQ cluster - enough material is available online. 
I want to load balance App2 instances. If I make queue consumer code a part of App2, then I am not sure if I can put an LB before App2 instances. Hence the proposal  - ... RabbitMQ -> workers -> LB -> App2 * N2

Comment: [Hit return before completing the last comment]
... The workers will only hand-off tasks to LB which load-balances requests across App2 instances. @NicolasLabrot Are you suggesting that using HAProxy, I will not need the extra layer of workers? I will still need some consumers to register with the queue, right?

Comment: If you run multiple instances of App2 connected to RabbitMQ it will be load balanced. Messages are given to consumers in a round-robin fashion

Comment: To complete Leon sentence, messages can be given to consumer when they can handle it, ie. once a message is handled and btw ACK, RabbitMQ push a new message to the consumer. Take a look at [consumer-prefetch](http://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html). Consumers are de facto load balanced because messages are queued into RabbitMQ server and push to consumer when they can handle it.

Comment: Correct. But as I mentioned, I require more advanced load balancing. To be more specific, let's there 5 tasks in the queue and 4 consumers. Rabbit will pass on first 4 tasks in the queue to the four consumers just fine. For the 5th task, I don't want one of the existing 4 consumers to handle it to avoid delay. I want a new 5th consumer to be spawned automatically, which can take the 5th task from Rabbit. That sort of dynamic scaling can't be achieved with Rabbit :-( Hence the proposal to use a specialized software/hardware (something like Amazon's elastic LB).

Comment: I better understand your need. RabbitMQ is only a message broker, it does not handle the client part.  The best may be to monitor the queue length/dequeue rate and spawn more instance when needed.